# PartialView to string

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to get in action HTML code which is rendered by PartialView. For example

```
var partView = PartialView("myView", myModel);
string content =??;
```

What should I put instead of question marks?

Comment: Have a look here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static string RenderPartialToString(string controlName, object viewData)
    {
        ViewPage viewPage = new ViewPage() { ViewContext = new ViewContext() };

        viewPage.ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(viewData);
        viewPage.Controls.Add(viewPage.LoadControl(controlName));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter tw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                viewPage.RenderControl(tw);
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
string content = RenderPartialToString("myView", myModel);
```